# placeholder use in perl DBI

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have perl script as following 
 `my $tb = 'rajeev';

$query = 'select * from table where name = ?'

$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);

$sth->execute($tb);`

Does $tb replaced by rajeev or 'rajeev' when query executes ? means does query executs  as 
 `select * from table where name = rajeev`
or
`select * from table where name = 'rajeev'`

Comment: Try it and see.  One compares `name` to a *column named `rajeev`*, and the other to a *string literal `'rajeev'`*.  Yes, as @bohica comments below, the statement is proabably not literally interpolated — see the [docs for `mysql_server_prepare`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-mysql/lib/DBD/mysql.pm) — but you'll be able to tell which semantics are in effect...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DBI handles all the escaping for you. In the case of a string, it will be `'rajeev'`. Calling `select * from table where name = rajeev` will give you an error.

If you provide a number, it will not add quotation marks because they are not needed.

See the [DBI Doc](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values). It also says:

> The quote() method should not be used with "Placeholders and Bind Values".

Using placeholders sometimes takes care of the quoting for you, depending on which DBD you are using. In your case the [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql/lib/DBD/mysql.pm#DESCRIPTION) calls `$dbh->quote()` as mentioned in the doc:

> An alternative approach is
>
> ```
> $dbh->do("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (?, ?)", undef, $number, $name);
> ```
>
> in which case the quote method is executed automatically.

If you have access to the [query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) you can check what the queries look like. If you have queries that take a long time you can also open a mysql console and say [`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html) to see a list of the running queries. That will also hold the complete SQL statements for you to look at. On Windows you could use [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/screenshots.php?which=host_processlist) to do it.

Comment: Personally I'd be careful not to mix the word "quoting" in any description of how placeholders are implemented. Many DBDs don't quote anything, they pass the SQL with placeholders intact and the parameters are passed separately when execute is called so there is no quoting as such.

Comment: FWIW, `... where name = rajeev` won't be an error if `rajeev` is a column name.

Comment: @pilcrow: that's right, but it's not what is intended here and not the behaviour the OP expects.

Comment: If someone looks for this: If there is a column namend `rajeev`, `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = rajeev` will return all the rows where the fields `name` and `rajeev` have the same values in that row.